# Python 3.12 Write Chinese in Excel CSV - UTF-8-SIG not work

Tags: python, excel, csv, utf-8

I am using Python 3.12.1 and upload it to AWS Lambda.

What I am doing is to get data from a MySQL DB (with some Chinese text in it) and export to Excel CSV.

Here is the code:

```py
# Copied from https://gist.github.com/tobywf/3773a7dc896f780c2216c8f8afbe62fc#file-unicode-csv-excel-py
with open(self.full_csv_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp)
    writer.writerow(['Row', 'Emoji'])
    for i, emoji in enumerate(['', '', '']):
        writer.writerow([str(i), emoji])
```

Result in (I use Excel: Data > From text to import, not double click)

[image]

This also did not work:

```py
with open(self.full_csv_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig') as csvfile:
    # Did not work
    csvfile.write("許蓋功")
    # Did not work, also tried 'utf-8'
    csvfile.write("許蓋功".encode('utf-8-sig').decode('utf-8-sig'))
```

Tried this, not working as well

```py
# Write CSV BOM mark
csvfile.write('\ufeff')  # did not work
csvfile.write(u'\ufeff')  # did not work
csvfile.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8').decode("utf8"))  # did not work
```

It will prepend the above text to the excel file, not BOM mark

It seems very clearly that the string is treated as UTF-8 encoded, but for some unknown and weird reason, it fails to convert to correct UTF-8.

Can you all please help?

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**
What I want to do is to attach this CSV file that contains Chinese character to an email and send it out in AWS Lambda.

Here is the code to send out email via SES:

```py
        # Create a multipart/alternative child container.
        msg_body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')

        # Encode the text and HTML content and set the character encoding. This step is
        # necessary if you're sending a message with characters outside the ASCII range.
        textpart = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT.encode(CHARSET), 'plain', CHARSET)
        htmlpart = MIMEText(BODY_HTML.encode(CHARSET), 'html', CHARSET)

        # Add the text and HTML parts to the child container.
        msg_body.attach(textpart)
        msg_body.attach(htmlpart)

        # Define the attachment part and encode it using MIMEApplication.
        att = MIMEApplication(open(ATTACHMENT, 'r', encoding='utf-8').read())

        # Add a header to tell the email client to treat this part as an attachment,
        # and to give the attachment a name.
        att.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename=os.path.basename(ATTACHMENT))

        # Attach the multipart/alternative child container to the multipart/mixed
        # parent container.
        msg.attach(msg_body)

        # Add the attachment to the parent container.
        msg.attach(att)

        # print(msg)

        response = ''

        try:
            #Provide the contents of the email.
            response = client.send_raw_email(
                Source=SENDER,
                # Destinations=[ RECIPIENT ],
                Destinations=RECIPIENT,
                RawMessage={
                    'Data':msg.as_string(),
                }
            )
        # Display an error if something goes wrong.
        except ClientError as e:
            print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
        else:
            print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
            print(response['MessageId'])
            print(f'Attachment: {ATTACHMENT}')
```

I am thinking about this line:

```py
RawMessage={
    'Data':msg.as_string(),
}
```

It may be the cause of all this mess.  But I have no idea how it works.

Comment: might work with utf16le encoding

Comment: @ti7 `LookupError: unknown encoding: utf16le`

Comment: @ElleryLeung, I ran your first example code (with the emojis) and was able to open the CSV in Excel Online.

Comment: Your code in the first example is good, that's as complex as it gets. The problem of getting Excel to open it correctly won't be solved with more Python code (manually writing a BOM, encode/decode). Did you try opening the CSV directly with Excel?

Comment: @ZachYoung I have to apologize for the rudeness I made on your gist.  I am sorry because it actually did not work on my code.  And yes, I solved this problem with another way and please see my update above.  Thank you.

Comment: @ZachYoung By the way, I've update my comment on your gist.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @ElleryLeung, glad you figured it out. If you’re not proud of that comment on the Gist (not mine BTW), I think you can just delete it. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

My actual use case is to

- Generate the CSV and
- Send it as attachment via AWS SES email

The keypoint is this: [In the sample code from AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/send-email-raw.html#send-email-raw-api), the `RawMessage` is actually converted to `string`, which means, the CSV and the UTF-8 BOM Mark is also converted to string, even if it is an attachment.

So, the CSV is generated correctly, the python code is correct, yet it is the SES python code that triggers this error.

To solve this problem is simple: You zip the CSV file generated and send it as attachment.

My gist on this code:
https://gist.github.com/alucard001/947a08291a457d423b1454d96461e6c0

Thank you.